# Issue on installing SQL Developer on Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: java, ubuntu, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to install SQL Developer on Linux (Ubuntu).
But I have an issue about the required JDK; the installer does not recognize my actual version of JSE; it is specified in the Oracle documentation that the JDK 1.6.11 (or later but less than 1.7.n) is required, but I'm not able to find it since the latest JDK 6 version is 1.6.0.45.
I'm pretty new on Linux so thanks for your patience :)
Anyone can help please?
Thanks a lot,
Sivounette

Comment: There's a [package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/+source/sqldeveloper-package/0.2.4)  for that (if that's what you need) also [this](http://linuxsagas.digitaleagle.net/2012/05/10/ubuntu-12-04-installing-oracle-sql-developer/) might help

Comment: What do you need ? u need java 1.6.11 ?

Comment: Am I supposed to restart the whole installing process of SQL Developer thanks to the package you have provided?

Comment: This question should probably go to stackexchange. StackOverflow is for _programming_ questions, not software installation questions. You may get a better response there.

Comment: Yes I need java 1.6.11, I cannot find it on the Oracle website... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have JDK7 installed you can use it with SQL Developer v3.2 - just ignore the warning.

Starting with v4 of SQL Developer, JDK7 will be required.

Some more info [here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/06/oracle-sql-developer-and-java-7/) on Java 7 and SQL Developer v3.2

Comment: You can find the Java 6 downloads here
 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you have a JDK 6 installed on your system; I've always used Sun (now Oracle) JDK.

In your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`:

```
JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk/
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

i usually just run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

in bash to install my oracle jdk

Answer (score 0):

1.6.11 is available for download here

[Java Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html)